# Typhoon - Initializer is not called

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

The selector specified as initializer is not called.

```
return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AppDelegate class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithString:)
                    parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
                        [initializer injectParameterWith:@"randomString"];
                    }];
}
```

I've set a breakpoint in `initWithString` and it never gets called. Furthermore, the string when I'm trying to use it, the string is empty.

And yes, I've specified the Typhoon configuration in my plist file, I've also made sure this method is called, and it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection to `AppDelegate<UIApplicationDelegate>` is a special case and only property or method injection is supported. This is because the AppDelegate is created outside of Typhoon.

Similarly objects created by Storyboards (Typhoon storyboard integration) only support property and method injection, not initializer injection.

Comment: `Similarly objects created by Storyboards`. So any non-programatically created view controller can't be injected with initializer? (Like initialViewController, view controllers created with storyboard segue?)

Comment: @LordZsolt That's right. Any view controller created outside of Typhoon will use whatever initializer was specified by the thing creating it. In the case of storyboards, that's `initWithCoder` . . initializer injection is only available for objects created *by* Typhoon.

Comment: At the current time, Storyboards and AppDelegate are the two cases where we declare objects in the Assembly, but are actually created outside of Typhoon. . there's no special, er, 'annotation' to document this, though it might've been useful to highlight the distinction.

Comment: Yeah, it might be a good idea. Currently there are examples which use  `injectProperty`, but it doesn't specifically say you can't use initializer injection :)

Comment: Ah right. I was talking about annotating it in code (using different class method or something). But at the very least it should be in the User Guide. Noted, will correct.

Comment: Oh and also, I can't use initializer injection if I instantiate the view controller from storyboard? (`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@""]`). Or can I work around this with TyphoonStoryboard?

Comment: Again, still no initializer injection for that case - TyphoonStoryboard will just provide property and method injection. There *can't be* initializer injection as storyboard created view controllers have their own contract requiring initWithCoder. On another but somewhat related note, if you bootstap Typhoon using plist integration, then the UIMainStoryboard (if any) declared in that plist  *is* a TyphoonStoryboard.